# Why do I keep getting a syntax error with my hash?

Tags: ruby

Below is a hash:

```
 hash = { 
     :home => {:team_name => "Brooklyn Nets", :colors => ['black','white'], 
       :players => { 
       { player_name: "Alan Anderson", 
         number: '0', 
         shoe: '16', 
         points: 22, 
         rebounds: 12, 
         assists: 12 , 
         steals:3 , 
         blocks:1,
         slam_dunks:1 }
      }
    },
   :away => [:team_name, :colors, :players]
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting this error?

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

It says this is happening at the `slam_dunks` line.

Comment: There is one extra pair of `{}` on the value of key `:players`, remove them.

Comment: Consider using either `key: value` or `:key => value` consistently. Mixing both is visually confusing. I would recommend the former unless you're concerned about backwards compatibility with Ruby < 1.9.

Comment: I think you should use a better IDE like rubymine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    hash = {
    home => {:team_name => "Brooklyn Nets", :colors => ['black','white'],
              :players => {
                  player_name: "Alan Anderson",
                    number: '0',
                    shoe: '16',
                    points: 22,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 12 ,
                    steals:3 ,
                    blocks:1,
                    slam_dunks:1 
              }
    },
    :away => [:team_name, :colors, :players]
}
```

Removed extra brackets inside **players** key and that was causing the error.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This works, however the reason i had it there is because there will be multiple players in that :players hash. when I set the :players => to an array of hashes that worked. The way that I'm trying above, is that not allowed in ruby? I planned on having the :players hash populated with more hashes containing 5 different players and their stats. Thanks

Comment: I dont think so {} means hash and hash needs to have a key.